# How do I fit the Comp length to a layers length in after effects?

Tags: after-effects

lets sayI have a comp in after effects with one layer. The layer appears to be longer than the actual comp. Is there any shortcut to make the comp automatically fit the length of the layer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This free script - [rd: Comp Setter](http://aescripts.com/rd-compsetter/) - should help.

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a script that does it with one click. Get it [here free](http://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/first-n-last/) (RD Comp Setter does a lot more as well, so use whichever one you like the looks of).